# How to search multiple occurences of a vimwiki tag?

Tags: tags, plugin-vimwiki

I'm using the vimwiki plugin and trying to figure out tagging with vimwiki-syntax-tags.

I can add a tag `:tag-example:` to a vimwiki .wiki file.

I can search `:VimwikiSearchTags tag-example` and it will find the tag properly.

If there are two instances of this tag, the search returns the first instance and displays `(1 of 2): :tag-example:`

Does anyone know how to go to the next tag instance found by the search?

Any other suggestions related to tagging / vimwiki would be appreciated as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The results from `:VimwikiSearchTags` are populated in the [`location-list`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#location%2dlist) window, so you can navigate using [`:lnext`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3alnext) and [`:lprevious`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3alprevious), or you can check all the results using [`:lopen`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3alopen).

To be honest, despite I have been using Vimwiki for several years, I didn't know about the tags. Maybe it is because my wikis are not that large (~2 MB at most), but I find it easier to simple [`:grep`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3agrep) (or [`:Ack`](https://github.com/mileszs/ack.vim)) everything, which is quite fast, instead of writing the tags in advance.

Comment: Be warned that the first time using `VimwikiSearchTags` may take a long while. I have been using Vimwiki since 2014, and have just discovered the `tag` syntax :) Sorting through my 2K+ notes should take a good number of minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick test on `:VimwikiSearchTags` vs `Ripgrep`

FTW - I'm going to stick with https://github.com/jremmen/vim-ripgrep

```
:Rg -i :tag-example
```

Comment: Tony, I've taken the liberty of [edit]ing your post with code-formatting and a slight capitalization. Your post would really benefit, however, from more details explaining what's going on

Answer (score 0):

After searching with `:VimwikiSearchTags`, use `:lopen`. This will open a Vim 'split'.

After selecting the note you want in the split, you can close the split created with `:lopen` by pressing `ctrl+o`.

If you decide to leave the split open so you can move between notes, you can navigate splits using `ctrl+w` then `h, j, k, or l`

Comment: This is pretty well covered in the accepted answer...

Comment: I actually learned about :lopen from the accepted answer about a year ago. At the time, it took me about an hour to find that the weird thing it did to my screen was called a split. I remember looking at the other answers for a clue about what type of object :lopen is and how to work with it. If my 20 second post saves at least one person an hour of searching, I'll consider that a victory

Comment: fair enough... perhaps 1-year-ago you would be glad to learn about the `:help` command (`:help :lopen`, for example)

Comment: Your point is well taken, and I agree - man pages are wonderful things, and folks should be encouraged to use them. In fact, I did know to use `:help :lopen` at the time - as a novice, the results were overwhelming.